# Collada .dae File rendering

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, collada

I am trying to convert .blend model to Collada .dae  format but after exporting to Collada .dae format my blender renderd model changed. How can i got same Model in Collada .dae format as it was in .blend?? Here is the images [image: .blend format]
[image: Collada .dae format]

Comment: It looks like not everything was exported. Make sure you've got the setting turned on for "export selected," or something along those lines.

Comment: yes i clicked all settings on

Answer (score 2):

Collada has very limited support for materials. The file format still uses the old Blinn, Phong lighting interaction formulas. Blender supports far mature material models that cannot be exported using Collada. Note that Collada was last updated in 2008, more then 10 years ago).

It is possible to extend collada to support different material models, but that only works as both applications (exporter in Blender and importer in other application) implement this extension. This is very difficult to maintain and therefore the extensions are really not useful at all.

An better option (if supported) is to use glTF. this is a file format that was created to supersees Collada and has far better material handling.